# Postgres return JSON element

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a JSON field ('ez_links') in a table ('bookings') and I wish to return a particular attribute/element ('Amount'), which represents the price of the booking.

In the example below, I want to return the value of '662', but NULL is returned.

```
select ez_links, ez_links-> 'Amount' AS price
FROM bookings
limit 1
```

Result:

| ez_links | price |
| --- | --- |
| {"integrator": "ezlinks", "TeeTimeReserveRecord": {"Fee": "Troon App Member", "Amount": "662",...........................................}} | NULL |

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This is a nested JSON,
you can do the following to access the Amount field

```
SELECT ez_links->'TeeTimeReserveRecord'->'Amount' as price FROM bookings
limit 1                                                                                                                  ;
```

I hope this was helpful.